# How can I change the order of the nodes in a simple linked list?

Tags: list, linked-list

If I have, for instance 5 nodes containing the variables 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, how can I link the nodes in order to obtain 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 ? (Change the first node with the third one, and the third with the first). Thanks.

Comment: what program language do you need it in?

Comment: Is this homework, or is there some greater systemic reason why you occasionally need to do this? If the latter, what exactly is it? We can give better answers if we understand your requirement more completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the node with key==1 and insert it after node 2.  Then remove node 3 and put it at the head of the list.  (By "node 3", I mean the node with key == 3, not the node that is third in the list, which is now the node with key == 1.)

Comment: Could you put it down, please (in C++ language or anything alike) ? I've been trying for hours to make it work and I still don't get any result.

Comment: @user1012732: You will need to describe the structure you are using for your list.  You might consider posting code.

Comment: struct node { int val; node *urm; };

Comment: What have you "been trying for hours"?  Unless you want to avoid walking the list 3 times, just do: list_delete( &head, n1 ); list_insert( &head, n1, k2 ); list_delete( &head, n3 ); list_push( &head, n3 ).  Probably the problem is in your definitions of the accessor functions.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, assuming that you already have pointers (or iterators) to the nodes, it is just a matter swapping the values in the two nodes.

Now, if your nodes contain more substantial data and you actually need to swap the nodes, it is just a matter of setting the prev/next pointers of one node to be the other's and vice versa. If the head of the list moves (and possibly the tail, depending on how your list is represented), you will have to update those variables, as well.